# Tkinter - How to trace expanding list of variables

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

What I am trying to do track when any values in a list of `StringVar` change, even when the list is expanding. Any additions to the list before the `trace` statement will result in the callback. But any additions afterward, such as when pressing a button, will not cause any callback.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0)

L = []

def add_entry(event):
    L.append(tk.StringVar())
    tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=L[len(L)-1]).grid(row=len(L),padx=(10,10),pady=(5,5))

add = tk.Button(frame,text='add Entry',command='buttonpressed')
add.grid(row=0)
add.bind('<Button-1>',add_entry)

for i in range(2):
    L.append(tk.StringVar())
    tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=L[len(L)-1]).grid(row=len(L),padx=(10,10),pady=(5,5))

for i in L:
    i.trace('w',lambda *arg:print('Modified'))

root.mainloop()
```

Modifying the first two `Entry`'s prints out `Modified`, but any `Entry`'s after the `trace` is run, such as the ones produced when a button is pressed, will not.

How do I make it so that `trace` method will run the callback for the entire list of variables even if the list is expanded?

Answer (score 0):

Simple suggestion, change your `add_entry` function to something like this:

```
def add_entry(event):
    L.append(tk.StringVar())
    tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=L[len(L)-1]).grid(row=len(L),padx=(10,10),pady=(5,5))
    L[len(L)-1].trace('w',lambda *arg:print('Modified'))
```

Extra suggestions:

1. This `add = tk.Button(frame,text='add Entry',command='buttonpressed')` is assigning a string to `command` option, means it will try to execute that string when button is clicked(which will do nothing). Instead, you can assign your function `add_entry` to `command` option and it will call that function when button is clicked and you can avoid binding Mouse Button1 click to your `Button`(Note: No need to use argument `event` in function when using like this). Read more [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm)
2. Python supports negative indexing of `List`, so you can call `L[-1]` to retrieve the last element in the list instead of calling `L[len(L)-1])`.
3. Once you change your `add_entry` function as suggested, you can reduce your code to

   ```
   import tkinter as tk

   root = tk.Tk()
   frame = tk.Frame(root)
   frame.grid(row=0)

   L = []

   def add_entry():
       global L
       L.append(tk.StringVar())
       tk.Entry(frame,textvariable=L[-1]).grid(row=len(L),padx=(10,10),pady=(5,5))
       L[-1].trace('w',lambda *arg:print('Modified'))

   add = tk.Button(frame,text='add Entry',command=add_entry)
   add.grid(row=0)

   for i in range(2):
       add_entry()

   root.mainloop()
   ```